# What is the purpose of `internalType` now generated by the Solidity compiler in ABIs?

Tags: solidity, abi

Newer Solidity 0.5.x compilers generate ABIs whose function and event parameters contain an `internalType` field as well as the usual `type`.

In the examples I've seen, `type` and `internalType` usually have the same value. But presumably that would not always be the case.

What is the meaning and purpose of this `internalType` field? When would it differ from the just-plain `type` field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/116913/fetching-internaltype-data-from-another-contract) does a nice job explaining the difference. Basically, `internalType` provides useful debugging information but is not required for contract encode/decode. So for example, an input `struct` will have a `type` of `tuple` and an `internalType` of the struct's declared name.