# Fetching InternalType data from another contract

Tags: web3js, nodejs, abi, typescript, query

basically I have this ABI for a contract

```
{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_DATA","type":"bytes"}],"name":"function","outputs":
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to fetch the value from _DATA and if it is, how would one achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

The "internalType" is the representation used by solidity.

For example the contract

```
contract B {
    struct View {
        uint x;
    }
    function foo(View memory bad) public view {
        this;
    }
}
```

Will produce the following ABI

```
[
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "components": [
                    {
                        "internalType": "uint256",
                        "name": "x",
                        "type": "uint256"
                    }
                ],
                "internalType": "struct B.View",
                "name": "bad",
                "type": "tuple"
            }
        ],
        "name": "foo",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]
```

The "type" says it is a tuple, but the "internalType" indicates it is a struct B.View.

The internal type is useful for debugging, but it is not required for the contract to encode/decode parameters.